# Node.js service poller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, node.js

I have an MVC web app that uses a jquery web request to generate the users notifications in a perceived async way. The notifications are built on request by each user on the site.

However I have been asked to make the notifications readily available as the happen.

This I would traditionally do using a windows service that called the same web method over http. I was thinking that this might be a good candidate functionality for using node.js

Is the any example code to call a http method in a loop and would that scale well ?

Answer (score 1):

found this package and seems to do what i needed

https://npmjs.org/package/node-cron-jobs

I also came across "forever" to run node as a child process that can be re-spawned if there are errors

Answer (score 0):

If you're already running on ASP.NET MVC take a look at [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR). This was written by Microsoft, is supported by them and provides functionality similar to the Socket.IO, node.js stack.

Comment: Yeah im aware of signalR but im not looking to do that kind of chanel coms. I want to run a long running single thread on the web server to poll a web service